# Discord.py: Overwrites of channel for member not working

Tags: discord.py

```
O = discord.PermissionOverwrite()
O.manage_webhooks=True
User=get(ctx.guild.members, name="User1")
await chan.set_permissions(User, overwrite=O)
```

What I'm doing wrong?
I get no errors but the channels permission for the member doesn't change.
Help me please.

Comment: How do you get the channel object

Answer (score 0):

First, there's a built in method called [get_member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member) that I strongly suggest you use, simply using a user name is pretty easy to get messed up as someone could just change their name. But it seems your code is rather sound, so some more information (if you need to use user name) such as how you're calling this and what `get` exactly is would help a ton!